# Format an Excel Sheet in Python

Tags: python, excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I am importing data from various web queries into a Jupyter Notebook and cleaning it in there and creating various forecasts etc.

The end output is required in an Excel file. 
However, the Excel file I create is simply a table of data and not very user-friendly.

One request I have from a user is to have the rows in the excel sheet in one color for weekends and another color for weekdays (the data is all datetime data).

Is there anyway of automatic the formatting of the excel sheet in python so that the whole process of creating the sheet is automated?

eg;
First row of headers would be **bold**
All rows representing weekend would be a one color. etc

At present I'm using the xlsxwriter

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Americas.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') 
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='WestFacilities')
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a particular package to create the Excel file or are you simply outputting a CSV?

Comment: At the minute I'm using the xlswriter;
```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Americas.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='WestFacilities')
```

Comment: Perhaps this article may be useful to you: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial02.html

Comment: i will have a look! thanks!

Comment: You'll need to either (A) do `df.to_excel()` and then re-open the file with `xlsxwriter` or whichever package, and then read each row & edit the format of cells which represent weekends, or (B) avoid the roundabout effort and define your own function to write to excel using `xlsxwriter` which will apply the necessary formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will help you
refer here https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red'})
worksheet.write('A1', 'Cell A1', cell_format)
```